# How to specify navigation LINK in rich:dropDownMenu?

Tags: jakarta-ee, richfaces, managed-bean

Using Richfaces I am trying to make UI. I am Following [showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dropDownMenu) Link

Demo code [DemoCode.java](https://github.com/ishaikovsky/Practical-RichFaces-Book/blob/master/menus-demo/src/main/java/org/richfaces/book/examples/DropDownBean.java) is not working.I am not able to specify link so that I can navigate from One page to another using links in Navigation link.

**Unfortunately demo code have dummy link.**  So I am not able to understand how to specify other page links in the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<rich:menuItem label="Add New" onclick="document.location.href='page2.xhtml'"  icon="/images/book-add-icon.png">
```

onclick solved my problem.  I followed following **link** to solve the issue. 
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dropDownMenu.jsf?c=menuItem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you expect the bean to look like, it has a bunch of methods like this:

```
public String doNew() {
    this.current = "New";
    return null;
}
```

the source is [here](https://github.com/richfaces/richfaces/blob/master/examples/showcase/src/main/java/org/richfaces/demo/dropdownmenu/DropDownMenuBean.java).

Comment: I am not sure what all code required to write apart from .xhtml